# What are the mathematical prerequisites for the string theory

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, string-theory

If one were to start self-studying string theory with a background only in calculus and some undergraduate linear algebra and ODE, what would the path and resources to cover to reach the string theory mathematical foundations.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=geometric+anatomy+of+theoretical+physics&rlz=1C1GCEA_enSI811SI811&oq=geo&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i59j35i39j0l2j69i60j69i61j69i60.3625j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Aqua thanks but are those mathematically rigorous enough?

Comment: The best it can be, but it will take you some time...:) And the lecturer is geniuous,

Comment: https://abstrusegoose.com/272 (Click on the image to see the continuation.)

Comment: @HansLundmark nice one and also more helpful than I though. Thanks!